# How to get the jmeter request body using ctx variable

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to fetch jmeter request body using  jmeter context class.

I am able to fetch the request body but its adding extra "()" . How to resolve this issue

def requestParamters = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments();
requestParamtersAsString = requestParamters.toString();

log.info("RequestBody is=" + requestParamters);

Results

2023-09-01 15:23:37,794 INFO o.a.j.v.J.JSR223 Listener: RequestBody is=useIDCSLogin=true()&text=mansa()

Answer (score 0):

[getArguments()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#getArguments()) function returns an instance of [Arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/config/Arguments.html) class instance, if you need the body most probably you need to get 1st argument value:

```
def requestParamters = prev.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion but i need all the parameters in one line because i want to save this request body in Grafana so that development team can quickly analyse and see what was send to the server.